# does Relativelayout in Android works in pixels or dpi?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

i'm trying to understand if the margin values of the Relativelayout in android are in pixels or dpi ?
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use both pixels and dpi. But if you want to make your application for multiple screen support then you have to prefer dpi. Because it will adjust the size according to screen size.

Comment: if i'm understanding correctly, the size if an image might change due to android modification, so an image in size of 70px might have different sizes on different devices, so how can i know in running time what the size of the image ?

Comment: No dear the size of image is fixed but you have to use dp for that instead of pixel. If you want to use the default size of the image then you will right "wrap_content" for that BUT if you want to use some specific size of any image or any control then dp is preferable. It will automatically adjust the size as per screen size of device.

Answer (score 1):

In xml you specifies measuring units such as `android:layout_marginTop="13dp"`. See [documentation about measuring units](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension).

In code you specifies masuring units in pixels (for example [margins](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html#setMargins%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)), but you can read dimensions from resources, where you can specify dimension in dp or sp, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose. Enter either `"5px"` or `"5dp"`, and it will adapt itself.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are refering to the values of certain methods. they are in pixels so you better convert the dpi values to pixels using displaymetrics